# Unsure how to update combobox in python with a database connected

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to figure out how to update the dropdown under a combobox in tkinter. 
This is what I currently have:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

#profile system
def prof_value_input():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    query = c.execute('SELECT prof FROM profile')
    prof = []
    for row in c.fetchall():
        prof.append(row)
    return prof

    c.close()
    conn.close()

def prof_add_btn():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    name=prof_input.get()
    newProf = c.execute('INSERT INTO profile VALUES (:prof)',{'prof':name})
    prof_input.set('')

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return 

prof_add_btn = Button(menu, text='add profile', width=10, command=prof_add_btn)
prof_input = ttk.Combobox(menu, width=30)
prof_input.grid(column=0, row=0)
prof_add_btn.grid(column=1, row=0)
prof_input['values'] = prof_value_input()
```

I'm getting really stuck and nowt sure where to go with this. 
Basically I am trying to make a profile system where you input a name into the combo box, it will then update in the sqlite3 database, after this I want it to update the combobox with the new profile that was added to the database.

Comment: Try adding `prof_input['values'] += (name,)` before `return` inside `prof_add_btn()`.  Better to check whether input name already exists before adding it to table.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS IT WORKED!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Also better to change `prof.append(row)` to `prof.append(row[0])` as `row` is a tuple with one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. In this example, I change from this

`prof_input = Combobox(menu, width=30)`

to this to call the method below

`self.cbox = Combobox(self, width = 10, postcommand = self.updtcblist)`

> Using a postcommand will enable you to callback to update (or even
>   create) the menu every time it is displayed.

Here in this method this will be updated.

```
def updtcblist(self):
    list = self.getPortLst()
    self.cbox['values'] = list
```

So in your code set a postcommand and set the function name to it.

Comment: OP is not using class, so where does the `self` come from?

Comment: This was just an example to illustrate it. Before giving the answer wanted to show exactly how it will work. :). Just updated to clarify it better

Comment: I see where you are getting to with the classes, but yeah I'm not using class.

Comment: yeah this one seems to be, im sure i'll have more in time hahah

Answer (score 0):

adding `prof_input['values'] += (name,)` before `return` inside `prof_add_btn()`

This code managed to get it functioning